# Integrating Google login android crashes app

Tags: android

I have been trying to follow this particular tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/ and other tutorials on how to integrate google login into my app. The problem is that when I choose an account. The app suddenly crashes, can anyone please help me.

This is the logcat I receive:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.gin.login, PID: 20197
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=7, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.gin.login/com.example.gin.login.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4734)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4777)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:211)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1754)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6918)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.gin.login.MainActivity.handleSignInResult(MainActivity.java:109)
                  at com.example.gin.login.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:156)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6833)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4730)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4777) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:211) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1754) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6918) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

My MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // Customizing G+ button
    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        String email = acct.getEmail();

        Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

        txtName.setText(personName);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfilePic);

        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            signIn();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            signOut();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("LOADING");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

This is my Grade(Project):

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

This is my Grade(Module):

```
  dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance! :D

Comment: Add your Activity Code Also

Comment: @MM I have added my codes sir :D

Comment: did you enable Google Sign-In?

Comment: @MM Ah sir sorry for being a Noob but how would you do that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: @MM Yes sir I already did that and downloaded the google-services.json file. And added it to the app folder sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
        String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
```

is throwing the error. Check if getPhotoUrl() is null or not before trying to invoke toString():

```
        String photoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl();
        String personPhotoUrl;
        if (photoUrl != null) {
            personPhotoUrl = photoUrl.toString();
        }
```

Comment: Yes sir you are correct. THank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

User don't have a photo, so you need to check `Uri` if is null or not.

`String photoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl() != null ? acct.getPhotoUrl().toString : "";`

Comment: Yes sir you are correct. THank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it! 

it sucks I could only accept 1 answer since both of you are correct. Thanks again sir!